# Cross Table of 5 Variables

Tags: r

I have an excel dataset its name (Variables) as follow (sample from data):

```
|Var1|Var2|Var3|Var4|Var5|
|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|1|
|0|0|0|0|2|
|0|0|0|1|0|
```

Variables values are as follow:
Var1 bear values (0,1,2,3)
Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5 bear values (0,1,2)
I would like to build cross table that contains all possible values with its count such as follow:

```
|Var1|Var2|Var3|Var4|Var5|count of similar event|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|0|0|1|0|
|0|0|0|0|2|0|
|0|0|0|1|0|1|
|0|0|0|1|1|1|
|0|0|0|1|2|0|
|0|0|0|2|0|6|
```

So |0|0|0|0|0| never appear, |0|0|0|2|0| appears 6 times (6 rows) and so on.

I tried following function table, crosstab and xtab but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R approach. First we need reproducible data:

```
set.seed(42)
Var1 <- sample(0:3, 100, replace=TRUE)
Var2 <- sample(0:2, 100, replace=TRUE)
Var3 <- sample(0:2, 100, replace=TRUE)
Var4 <- sample(0:2, 100, replace=TRUE)
Var5 <- sample(0:2, 100, replace=TRUE)
Variables <- data.frame(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5)
str(Variables)
# 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Var1: int  0 0 0 0 1 3 1 1 0 3 ...
#  $ Var2: int  1 0 1 0 1 2 0 0 2 1 ...
#  $ Var3: int  2 1 1 2 2 0 2 1 0 2 ...
#  $ Var4: int  2 2 1 2 0 2 2 0 1 1 ...
#  $ Var5: int  1 1 0 1 0 2 0 1 1 2 ...
```

Now we just need to create a multi-dimensional table and flatten it:

```
Var.tbl <- xtabs(~Var1+Var2+Var3+Var4+Var5, Variables)
Var.dbf <- as.data.frame.table(Var.tbl)
head(Var.dbf)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Freq
# 1    0    0    0    0    0    0
# 2    1    0    0    0    0    0
# 3    2    0    0    0    0    0
# 4    3    0    0    0    0    1
# 5    0    1    0    0    0    0
# 6    1    1    0    0    0    2
```

This is not in the order you used in your example. To get that order use

```
Var.dbf2 <- with(Var.dbf, (Var.dbf[order(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5), ]))
head(Var.dbf)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Freq
# 1    0    0    0    0    0    0
# 2    1    0    0    0    0    0
# 3    2    0    0    0    0    0
# 4    3    0    0    0    0    1
# 5    0    1    0    0    0    0
# 6    1    1    0    0    0    2
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly

**tidyverse**

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(
  list(
    Var1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
    Var2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L,
             0L),
    Var3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
    Var4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L),
    Var5 = c(0L,
             1L, 2L, 0L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-4L)
)

vars <- syms(c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5"))

df %>% 
  group_by(!!!vars) %>% 
  add_count() %>% 
  complete(Var1 = 0:3, Var2 = 0:2, Var3 = 0:2, Var4 = 0:2, Var5 = 0:2, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 1,296 x 6
#>     Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5     n
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#>  1     0     0     0     0     0     1
#>  2     0     0     0     0     1     1
#>  3     0     0     0     0     2     1
#>  4     0     0     0     1     0     1
#>  5     0     0     0     1     1     0
#>  6     0     0     0     1     2     0
#>  7     0     0     0     2     0     0
#>  8     0     0     0     2     1     0
#>  9     0     0     0     2     2     0
#> 10     0     0     1     0     0     0
#> # ... with 1,286 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**updated**

```
df_count <- df %>% 
  group_by(!!!vars) %>% 
  add_count()

Var1 = 0:3
Var2 = 0:2
Var3 = 0:2
Var4 = 0:2
Var5 = 0:2

expand_grid(!!!vars) %>% 
  left_join(df_count) %>% 
  mutate(n = replace_na(n, 0))
```

Comment: By using this a new dataframe was built. but what if I wanted to count my dataset events using similar structure?